# Where'd the Google camera app go?

Tags: applications, google-apps, google-camera

I have a Motorola Moto Z but I can't find the official Camera app by Google. Can anyone provide me with the Play Store link?

Comment: According to this [last reported blog](http://phoneradar.com/google-camera-app-missing-google-play-store-download-apk/), Google camera app is missing from PS in some regions. This blog has a link for download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @beeshyams said in their comment, the Google Camera app is not available in some regions on the Play Store. This [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera) is to the listing on the Play Store. If you can access the listing from that link, then you're one of the lucky few countries that can. If you cannot, you will have to download it from a reputable third party website such as [APKMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/camera/camera-4-2-035-141213305-release/).

Do take note of the minimum supported Android version when using APKMirror as well as the fact that there are two variants for different processor architectures. If the minimum version is too high, I recommend moving to the most recent one that supports your OS version. If there are two variants available for whichever version you choose and if your first download doesn't install, try the other variant.

DISCLAIMER: You will have to enable Installation from Unknown Sources in order to install from a third party site. This is highly recommended against as it enables the possibility of malicious applications being installed on your device.

Comment: @AbAppletic they tend to make the release worldwide compatible then proceed to lock it out of the majority of regions, just the way is unfortunately :(

Comment: I think this is the first time that I faced this: I can't search Google Camera on Play Store (browsing all apps by Google doesn't include this too), but I can install it through the link to the Play Store listing you provided. Usually, when I can't search an app on Play Store, 99.99% I won't be able to install it using its direct link to the listing, either due to country restriction or unsupported device. Weird... but true story...